# How to use exportFunction in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
exportFunction(function(){
    var document = oldContentDocumentGetter.call(this);
    if (document){
        interceptWindow(document.defaultView);
    }
    return document; 
}, window)
```

This script works well on firefox, but does not work on chrome. Please help me. Thanks.
The error is:

> Error handling response: ReferenceError: exportFunction is not defined

Comment: that seems to be old school extension (XPCOM?)

Comment: exportFunction, cloneInto and createObjectIn do a meaningful action only in Firefox and only in the context of a content script. In Chrome you'll have to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)