# Equivalent of exportFunction or cloneInto for classes?

Tags: javascript, class, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

The title says it all. I'm trying to **inject a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)** into the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object) / default scope of affected webpages, from a [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions). (I have no objections to supporting Chrome; however, I'm tagging this question as Firefox-specific for now, since it [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265222/how-to-use-exportfunction-in-chrome-extension#comment104740240_59265222) that Chrome does not yet support this use-case at all.)

- For functions, [`exportFunction()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts#exportfunction) may be used to inject functions into the global object.
- For Objects, [`cloneInto()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts#cloneinto) may be used.
- However, **neither of these** seemed to work for a `class`.

Here is a sample `content_script` that I've been using for troubleshooting:

```js
console.log("Content script initializing...");

function patch_function(f, name, dest=window) {
    exportFunction(f, dest, {defineAs: name});
    console.log(`Patched function ${name} into window!`);
}

function patch_object(o, name, dest=window) {
    window.wrappedJSObject[name] = cloneInto(o, dest, {cloneFunctions: true});
    console.log(`Patched object ${name} into window!`);
}

let basicObject = {'hello': 'world'};

class MyClass {
    constructor(x=7) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    return_x() {
        return this.x;
    }
}

console.log("Patching...");

// This works PERFECTLY from the webpage...
patch_object(basicObject, 'basicObject');

// ...but neither of these works! Swap the comment to try out the other one
//patch_function(MyClass, 'MyClass');
patch_object(MyClass, 'MyClass');


console.log("Content script done!")
```

In particular, running a statement such as `(new MyClass(3)).return_x()` yields `Permission denied to access property "return_x"` no matter how it was injected!

How can I inject a custom `class` (which — crucially — might even call WebExtension-privileged code) into a webpage from a WebExtension? (Or, if not possible: what is the tracker # for this — I [can't currently find it](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Abugzilla.mozilla.org+webextension+inject+%22class%22).)

Comment: The context of this is: I need to **monkey-patch** some additional behavior onto [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), in a **drop-in compatible** manner.

Comment: Putting here for either my own reference or for someone nimbler than I to scoop, as a possible wedge into solving this… not the full-on usurpation of the object I'd hoped for, but I guess if you just monkey-patched [all](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) the methods and properties you could have a Theseus situation…: https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/apirequest/How-We-Captured-AJAX-Requests-with-a-Chrome-Extension/

Comment: Since this looks like a cross origin problem, could [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.exportFunction#cross-origin_checking) help maybe?

Comment: @MinusFour I'm not sure… it's not clear whether that article fragment still applies post-XPCOM (the documentation around the function is so shoddy it's a toss-up whether it's just not-documented-yet on the new docs or has genuinely been removed), but in any case adding it to the code in the OP as-written neither fixed it nor broke it further. I'll keep that in mind for a potential deep-exportFunction-based-clone solution if something that looks like it should work isn't, however…

Comment: It's quite likely a limit of FF's implementation so just use the old ES5 way of declaring classes via a function + methods on its prototype.